# CSR: Group header returns different result after an AJAXRefreshView

Tags: client-side-rendering

I do **not** touch the grouping in my CSR template at all

On Page load the **View** grouping looks like the standard 2010 style

#### Before:

[image]

#### Action:

Setting a choice triggers an AJAXRefreshView

(so the **exact same** CSR code is executed for the whole View)

(*Yes, I am doing Forms in a View (every List-**Item** is Survey answer)... kinda cool as SharePoint does most of the layout & logic work*)

Yet, now the Group header looks like this..

**What gives?**

#### After:

[image]

#### Update #1

Sometimes.. late at night... you hate SharePoint

Force a redraw of the View on **first** OnPostRender

And don't tell the customer tomorrow

```
            _spYield(function(){
                iCSR.SP.refreshView(ctx,false);
            },100);
```